# Extract Values from multiple columns in R matrix as numeric and plot histogram

Tags: r, dataframe, histogram

I'm a beginner in R. I can't do a histogram of the entire matrix:

hist(my.matrix)

because:

```
Error in hist.default(my.data): 'x' must be numeric
Traceback:

1. hist(my.data)
2. hist.default(my.data)
3. stop("'x' must be numeric")
```

I figured out that if I select any column (e.g. my.data[1:400,1] or my.data[1:400,2]) is.numeric returns TRUE; however, my.data[1:400,1:400], is.numeric returns false.  I just wanna get the data of all columns and distribution of all the data in my matrix. I tried as.vector, but that didn't work.  How?

Comment: For us to help you, you should share data we can use that's relevant to this problem. If your data is large, give a subset that will help us demonstrate what you want. If your data is sensitive, give us a small made-up dataset with the same properties for the purposes of answering your question.

Comment: I think your data are a `data.frame`. Just do `hist(as.matrix(my.matrix))`.

Comment: Try `my.data[is.numeric(my.data)]`

Comment: The information offered so fat strongly suggests that you do not have an R matrix. It's probably an R data.frame. The suggestion from Rohit makes no sense at all in my opinion.